# Multilevel / Nested ANOVA for six lakes and parasitized / non parasitized fish

Tags: r, anova

I have six lakes sampled (A1, A6, A8, B2, B7, D7) with fish measurements for parasitized (1=P) and non-parasitized fish (0=NP). I want to compare similarities or differences between each lake for three different variables (Condition Factor K, Heptosomatic Index HSI, and Gonadosomatic Index GSI)

I am having trouble trying to grasp how to write this in code for R. I know this would give me a normal model for length-weight relationships compared to interaction terms K + GSI + HSI, but it would not compare the lakes or NP and P fish that I want to look at:

```
Ppungitius <-aov(Total Weight ~ Total Length + K + GSI + HSI, data=fishdata)
```

But how would I go about using "Lake" and "Parasites" to compare these variables between each lake and also to compare parasitized vs non parasitized fish? I believe it is a nested anova I am looking for, I just can't figure out the notation with six lakes and P vs NP fish.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated...